# NMARoutingErrorNetworkCommunication Explanation

Tags: here-api

For some of the users of our app, they are consistently getting a NMARoutingErrorNetworkCommunication error whenever they try to do navigation.

They have attempted to retry the routing to no success. They have switched from wifi to cellular, tried different locations, and routing parameters with no success. They have switched from Truck to Car routing with no success either.

On top of this, everything else works. The map screen is fine, Google routes fine, and Apple routes fine.

From what I can tell, this is a rejection by the server for routing. Is there any more explanation as to what this bug is, or how it might be debugged? It effects probably 2% or less of our users, making it hard to recreate. But since it's an error with the HERE servers itself, it makes me wonder how much control I have to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

NMARoutingErrorNetworkCommunication  - The online route calculation request failed because of a networking error. The route calculation request should be retried.

It could be possible that the request coming from your application could have some incorrect params that may be causing long enough to receive from our end, or routing request is blocking. If you could more details with code snippet, how this is calling request at your end.